# Why this 'if' does not execute in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    //initialization of array lists 
    ArrayList<Integer> indexArray=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<Integer> sortedIndex=new ArrayList();
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your index number ");
    int index=in.nextInt();
    int ind=0;  
    while (index > 0) {            
        indexArray.add(index%10);            
        index=index/10;
    }
    int indexArraySize=indexArray.size();
    int max=0;
    int min=9;
    while(indexArraySize>0){
       int digit=indexArray.get(indexArraySize-1);
       if(min>digit){
           min=digit;
       }
       if(max<digit){
           max=digit;
       }           
       indexArraySize--;            
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum= "+max);
    System.out.println("Minimum= "+min);
}
```

This code returns correct values for any integer input except for 00000000

For 00000000 it gives 
Maximum= 0
Minimum= 9

which means it doesn't get executed

```
if(min>digit){
    min=digit;
}
```

What is the reason for this and how can I correct this?

Comment: Run the code in an IDE debugger and step through it one line at a time, examining the variables as you go.  Please do this BEFORE posting a question here.

Comment: it would get executed, but your `ArrayList` is empty, because the while condition isn´t valid at any point(both of them)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As well as debugging code before posting, please take the time to format your code into as readable a fashion as possible. I'll edit this question to show you want I mean, but please do this for your own next post.

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't get executed.  But not for the reason you think.  It doesn't get executed in the `000000` case because `arrayIndexSize` will be zero.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. I will improve the question and check it in IDE debugger here after. I am quite new to programming. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first while loop add all the digits of the input number to the `ArrayList`, unless the input number is 0, in which case nothing is added to that `List`.

Therefore, the `min` and `max` variables retain their default values.

You could solve it by adding a test for 0 :

```
if (index == 0)
    indexArray.add(0);
else {
    while (index > 0) {
        indexArray.add(index%10);
        index=index/10;
    }
}
```